# Changing numbers of equations

Tags: numbering

I numbered an equation in an equation environment in the introduction of a paper alluding to a formula that I prove later in the paper. However when I actually state the theorem and restate the formula in the equation (before proving it) the numbering differs than what I had when I first mentioned it. How can I change the number of the equation that appears later in the paper so that it matches what I have earlier?

EDIT: So it seems I may have been to vague. In the paper I am writing, I work out a few specific examples in regards to what I am writing about and then end the introduction with a conjecture that reads to the effect \begin{equation} (formula for what we believe will be the answer in the general case) \label{awesome equation} \end{equation}. Then I discuss a few other things (lemmas and such) before proving that (\ref{awesome equation}) is true.

Once everything is in place, then I state the theorem for the general case: \begin{thm} For blah blah blah in the general case we have: \begin{equation} (same equation as we had before) \label{still want everything to be the same} \end{equation} \end{thm}.

When I compile, the numbering of these two equations is different, but they are the exact same and so I would like there numbers to be the same. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want. (A MWE, please!) Is the `\tag` macro what you are after?

Comment: `\begin{equation}\label{eq:my important equation} ... \end{equation}` some text equation `\ref{eq:my important equation}` should work. For say anything more, (non)MWE please!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Not sure what MWE is. I edited the post so hopefully it is more clear what I am after.

Comment: @Zarko I am not trying to reference it, but rather restate.

Comment: Try something like `\tag{\ref{eq-in-intro}}` and check if this has any side effect on the numbering of the equations that  follow.